# A Thread as an object Java

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, runnable

I want a collection of objects that inherit from `Thread`; each object running in it's own thread.

I tried `extends Thread` and called `super()` thinking that'd ensure a new thread is created; but no... only `main` is the running thread :(

Everyone tells me, "implement `Runnable` put the code you want in `run()` and put it in a thread-object".
I can't do this because of 2-reasons:

1. My collection-elements aren't of-type `Thread` and if I polymorph I'll have to change all it's dependencies.
2. `run()` can't contain an entire class... right?

So I want to know firstly, if what I want to do is even possible and
secondly, if so, how to do it?

Comment: Welcome back Olivier10178. run() can contain an inner class.

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Surely you could just extend Thread? You then need to call Thread.start() to make them run.

Comment: You should generally avoid extending `Thread`.  What are you trying to accomplish? Why can't you just pass `Runnable`s to `Thread`?

Comment: What is the object type?and...you want each object to call it's methods in separate threads.right?

Comment: Well..You can always do this....`extends Threads implements Runnable`

Comment: why can't you go for ExecutorService?

Comment: Too complicated; explain it to me like I'm 12, I only have 30mins or I'm scrapping the threading all-together. Poor main's gonna have his work cut out for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` just calls the parent constructor (in your case the default `Thread` constructor). The method to actually start the new thread is `start()`. As others have said, it's poor design to extend `Thread`.

Yes, you can create a class that implements `Runnable`

```
class MySpecialThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

and you can start it in a new thread like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MySpecialThread());
// Add it to a collection, track it etc.
t.start(); // starts the new thread
```

1- You can use collections of `Runnables` *OR* collections of `Thread`s using the example below.

```
MySpecialThread m = new MySpecialThread();
List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
runnables.add(m);
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
threads.add(new Thread(m));
```

2- A method can't *contain* a class, but the above example `MySpecialThread` is a class that behaves like any other class. You can write a constructor, add methods and fields, etc.

Comment: So I need a separate List to contain the Threads is what you're saying. I can't just have 1 list where the object is equivalent to the thread?

Comment: I was just saying you can choose either. If you want a list of `Thread` objects, you don't need the list of `Runnable`s. I was just showing that either option is possible.

Comment: If I have a List of Runnables only; how then do I start threads??

Comment: new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();  // MyRunnable is your Runnable task

Comment: Right, and I don't need to reference them, at any point, as they can manage themselves? Also, if I have nothing in  run()  will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `ExecutorService`

Let's have a sample code on usage of `ExecutorService`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ExecutorServiceDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Future<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
            CallableTask callable = new CallableTask(i+1);
            Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callable);
            list.add(future);
        }
        for(Future<Integer> fut : list){
            try {
                System.out.println(fut.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

class CallableTask implements Callable<Integer>{
    private int id = 0;
    public CallableTask(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer call(){
        // Add your business logic
        return Integer.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If you want to use Thread instead of ExecutorService, below code should work for you.

```
import java.util.*;

class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    private int id = 0;
    public MyRunnable(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void run(){
        // Add your business logic
        System.out.println("ID:"+id);
    }
}
public class RunnableList{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(i+1));
            list.add(t);
            t.start();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have RunnableList??